# how to calculate multiple aggregates on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create summary of my table with aggragate functions such as max,min,avg 
The query is something like this

```
select 'avg',avg(column1) as 'avg_resp',avg(col2) as 'ncount' from table
union all
select 'max',max(column1),max(col2) from table
union all 
select 'min',min(column1),min(col2) from table;
```

Can it be done in better way??
PS: I want to use it for REST API  so I am trying not to transpose/elongate the final result.

REST API model  from my current code:

```
{ 
 avg_resp:[min,max,avg],
 ncount: [min,max,avg]
}
```

Comment: It does not have a better answer then suggested in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible

```
  select avg(column1) as avg_resp,
   avg(col2) as ncount,
   max(column1) as max_col1,
   max(col2) as max_col2,
   min(column1) as min_col1,
   min(col2) as min_col2
  from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
select 
  avg(column1) as 'avg_resp', 
  avg(col2)    as 'ncount',
  max(column1) AS Max1,
  max(col2)    AS MAx2, 
  min(column1) AS Min1,
  min(col2)    AS Min2
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put everything in one select statement

```
select avg(column1) as avg_resp,
       avg(col2) as ncount,
       max(column1) as max_col1,
       max(col2) as max_col2,
       min(column1) as min_col1,
       min(col2) as min_col2
from your_table
```

Comment: sorry web design was confusing word so changed it with REST API